# Facing "no implicit conversion of nil into String" error inside eval statement

Tags: ruby

Exercise :Creating Classes from CSV Started
Read a csv format file and construct a new class with the name of the file dynamically. So if the csv is persons.csv, the ruby class should be person, if it's places.csv, the ruby class should be places 
Also create methods for reading and displaying each value in "csv" file and values in first row of csv file will act as name of the function. 
Construct an array of objects and associate each object with the row of a csv file. 
For example the content of the csv file could be 
name,age,city 
gaurav,23,karnal 
vilok,23,hissar

My expected output is correct. I am able to print the method name as first row of CSV and remaining lines of code has been evaluated and printed as strings on console. 
But along with expected output I'm facing below error.

```
classes_from_CSV.rb:21:in `eval': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in new_method'
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:25:in `call'
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

I just want to know how should I remove this error and what is the correct way of evaluating string type user input inside dynamic methods.

```
require 'csv'

class CsvManipulator
  def first_line_csv
    CSV.open("Input.csv", 'r') { |csv| csv.first }
  end

  def remaining_line_csv
    text = File.readlines("Input.csv")[1..-1].join()
    csv = CSV.parse(text, headers: true)
  end
end

class MethodCreator < CsvManipulator
  def initialize(class_name)
    @klass = Class.new
    Object.const_set(class_name, @klass)
  end
  def new_method(method_name, code_str)
    @klass.class_eval do
      puts define_method(method_name) { eval(puts"#{code_str}") }
    end
  end
  def call(method_name)
    @klass.new.send(method_name)
  end
end

class_name  = "Input"
obj = MethodCreator.new(class_name)
method_name = (obj.first_line_csv).join(', ')
code_str = obj.remaining_line_csv
obj.new_method(method_name, code_str)
puts obj.call(method_name)
```

Expected output : 
name, age, city
gaurav,23,karnal
vilok,23,hissar

Actual output :

name, age, city
gaurav,23,karnal
vilok,23,hissar

```
classes_from_CSV.rb:21:in `eval': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in new_method
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:25:in `call'
    from classes_from_CSV.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you share the CSV file that you're parsing?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Comment: @GProst                                                                                                                           ```                                                                                                             name,age,city \n
gaurav,23,karnal \n
vilok,23,hissar                                                                                                                   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only calling `eval` in one place, so the error is not hard to find:

```
eval(puts"#{code_str}")
```

`puts` returns `nil`, so you are effectively calling

```
eval(nil)
```

However, `eval` must be called with a string.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.